# My drag n Drop event cause doubling items with clicking?

Tags: events, click

I did a listbox with drag & drop items
Drag and drop is working perfectly
but if I click only any item it adds it to the list
I did not try changing drag threshold since I didn't know how to rach and change SystemParameterInfo.

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0) return;
    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);
    if (dde1 == DragDropEffects.All) {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code you're having trouble with.  No one here will be able to help you with the information you've provided.

Comment: private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            

            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
                return;

            int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
            string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
            DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);

            if (dde1 == DragDropEffects.All)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y));
            }

    
        } I also tried to reach for drag threshold without success

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.